# Here maps cordova plugin

Tags: android, maps, cordova-plugins

I was searching for a cordova plugin for the HERE map sdk but I could not find any. I was hoping to find somebody that has done some work in this directions and is willing to share.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: looking for same thing